# Docker React could not find required file index.js

Tags: docker

I know there are many other versions of this question, the answers to which I've tried, but I'm just not getting this. I'm new to Docker, but have looked at lots of tutorials, followed the Docker docs, and I'm just not sure how to dig any deeper. I have a React frontend which I'm trying to get a running container on before working on the docker compose side (the backend and image/container for mongo are working fine).

I keep getting the error:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts start
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.js
  Searched in: /frontend/src
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here is the command I'm running- trying to set up a volume at the same time so I can pass updates to the running container - the image is tagged as demofrontend

```
docker run -v /home/Octochart/frontend/src:/frontend/src --name demo-frontend --rm -p 3000:3000 -it demofrontend:latest
```

And heres the frontend's docker file:

```
FROM node:17-alpine

WORKDIR /frontend

#COPY package.json .

#RUN npm install

COPY public /frontend/public
COPY src /frontend/src
COPY package.json /frontend/package.json
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

I initially had (what seems to be the standard approach) this listed for the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:17-alpine

WORKDIR /frontend

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ] #I had been using yarn on my local prior to this, tried npm with the same error
```

I've confirmed over and over that the index.js file is there, here's the local list from the src folder:

```
App.js       
assets          
ErrorBoundary.js  
logo.svg       
MuiTheme.js    
redux               
setupTests.js  
views
App.test.js  
DeleteAlert.js  \
index.js          
MiniDrawer.js  
navigation.js  
reportWebVitals.js  
utilities
```

index.js is there, so I must be messing it up with the COPY stage, but even with COPY . . which should grab everything, I get the error. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I seem to have resolved the initial issue by adding / to the COPY stage on the dockerfile and specifying the folders like shown above, so COPY /src /frontend/src

This allowed me to create the image without issue which I'm not sure when that happened from before, but it was, now again trying to the run the container with the volume, I get the same error, index.js is not found in /frontend/src.

Running docker run -it demofrontend sh and listing out the folders, here is the frontend/src:

```
App.js              ErrorBoundary.js    assets              navigation.js       setupTests.js
App.test.js         MiniDrawer.js       index.js            redux               utilities
DeleteAlert.js      MuiTheme.js         logo.svg            reportWebVitals.js  views
```

index.js is clearly there. I was able to get past this with just:

```
docker run -it demofrontend
```

so maybe its an issue with how I'm trying to set up the volume?